# Trouble with printing a string in OCaml

Tags: printing, types, output, ocaml, format-string

The code compiles without the print statement. However with the print statement I get the error on that line that `Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type int`. I've also tried `print_string numDigits`

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in
    let numDigits = string_of_int num in
    Printf.printf "%s" numDigits

    let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
    temp * (10 * String.length(numDigits)) + rev_int num;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a semicolon missing at the end of the Printf line.

An alternative os the start this line with `let () =` and end it with `in`.

Comment: Thank you; this fixed it! Just out of curiosity, on other code `printf` ends with either no semi-colon or with two. Why one in this case?

Comment: 2 semicolons is obsolete and intended to separate top-level definitions. I recommend not to use it outside of the ocaml interactive loop (where it is mandatory anyway).

Comment: 1 semicolon is to separate side effects (`unit` typed values); ex: `let x = ref 0.0 in for i = 1 to 5 do x := !x +. 1./.float i; Printf.printf"%f\n"!x; done;` . The compiler ensures that the values before the `;` are of type `unit` (here, the values `x := !x +. 1./.float i` ; `Printf.printf"%f\n"!x` and the whole loop.

Answer (score 0):

To add further illustration for anyone looking at this from the future, OCaml doesn't really care about whitespace. Your code parses as:

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in
    let numDigits = string_of_int num in
    Printf.printf "%s" numDigits

let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
temp * (10 * String.length(numDigits)) + rev_int num
```

Two things are wrong here.

Firstly, `Printf.printf "%s" numDigits` returns `unit` while the other branch of your conditional returns `int`. This is not going to compile and gives you a type error.

Secondly, if this were a complete program, the following would not be a valid toplevel definition.

```
let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
temp * (10 * String.length(numDigits)) + rev_int num
```

As hinted in the existing answer, you likely wanted to use a `;` to have a side-effect in the form of the print, and then return that value.

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in
    let numDigits = string_of_int num in
    Printf.printf "%s" numDigits;
    let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
    temp * (10 * String.length(numDigits)) + rev_int num
```

Alternatively, you can bind the side-effect-causing expression to `()`.

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in
    let numDigits = string_of_int num in
    let () = Printf.printf "%s" numDigits in
    let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
    temp * (10 * String.length(numDigits)) + rev_int num
```

As a final note, you have some unnecessary parentheses and `Printf.printf "%s"` is just `print_string` (as you seem aware).

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in
    let numDigits = string_of_int num in
    let () = print_string numDigits in
    let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
    temp * 10 * String.length numDigits + rev_int num
```